# JSP - Java error: Only a type can be imported. main.Config resolves to a package

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat8.5

I went through the similar questions but the answers doesn't seem to solve the question. I have downloaded this simple project from GitHub https://github.com/PCS0725/blogprabhat to learn java web development. I am using Eclipse for this. I am getting error in the importing java class files. In Eclipse it shows The import java.util cannot be resolved.

```
<%@page import="main.Config"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="main.datalayer.Database"%>
<%@page import = "main.model.Article" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=Config.style %>" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">

      <a href="."><img id="logo2" src="<%=Config.imageSrc %>" alt="My name here"></a>
       <ul id="headlines">
      <%
            ArrayList<Article> articles = Database.getList(Config.numRows); //number of articles to show on homepage
            int i = 0;
            for(i=0; i<articles.size();++i)                     //parse all articles and diplay in a format
            {
                int id = articles.get(i).getId();
                Date date = articles.get(i).getPublicationDate();
                java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
                         new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM ");
                String dte = sdf.format(date);
                //passing a paramter(viewArticleId) to viewArticle.jsp to specify the article
        %>
                <li>
                    <h2>
                        <span class="pubDate"><%=dte %></span><a href="viewArticle.jsp?viewArticleId=<%=id%>"><%=articles.get(i).getTitle()%></a>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="summary"><%=articles.get(i).getSummary() %></p>
            </li>
            <%
            }
            %>
         </ul>
        
        <p><a href="archive.jsp">Article Archive</a></p>
        <div id="footer" style = "text-align : center">
          <%=Config.footer %><a href="loginForm.jsp">Site Admin</a>
         </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error on the Server :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\brijr\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\blogprabhat\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. main.Config resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\brijr\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\blogprabhat\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. main.datalayer.Database resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [18] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\brijr\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\blogprabhat\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. main.model.Article resolves to a package
```

Comment: This is Java 101.  Believe the error messages.  main.Config is a package name.  If you want to import all the classes in the package, try changing it to <%@page import="main.Config.*"%>

Comment: @duffymo to be fair I'm as surprised as OP is, given the link. In particular https://github.com/PCS0725/blogprabhat/tree/master/src/main seems to actually contain a class named `Config`

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  Why does the error message say "generated java file"?  Was the source code compiled to .class files and packaged properly?  Impossible to tell from the question text. src/main is a Maven directory convention, not usually designated as a package.  I think the source code is not properly done.

Comment: @duffymo Yes, I am newbie actually. Even after importing all the classes of main.Config, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Where did you find this repo?  Why are you using it?  Did you create that code?

Comment: @duffymo I am UNI student and I have a project submission so I searched on github for java blog web projects and this is the closest to what I have to submit. I didn't write the code.

Comment: Either the repo is bad or you're not using it properly.  Like I said, src/main is a Maven standard.  "main" should not be a package.  I would create a package underneath src/main.  I would either fix it or find another repo.  How does using another person's repo suddenly turn into your project?

Comment: One more word of advice: scriptlet code in JSPs, and JSPs in general, are another failed 90s technology.  You should rethink all of this.  What uni is teaching you to use JSPs?  REST service, HTTP, and HTML pages are the way to go, not JSPs.

Comment: The generated file being referred to in **Tomcat's** error message is the result of it translating your JSP into the source for a Java Servlet, which it then compiles and runs for you. That part is normal. You should look in `C:\Users\brijr\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\blogprabhat\` and see why it thinks `main.Config` might be a package, or directory, at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem i was i importing my class User from a package p1 but i was getting this error :

> Only a type can be imported. p1.User resolves to a package

all i did is change `pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"` to `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` and it worked !

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@page import="p1.User" %>
```

Changing the page encoding to **UTF-8** might have fixed the problem by ensuring better handling of characters and byte sequences. Sometimes, character encoding issues can cause unexpected errors in code interpretation. Switching to UTF-8 possibly resolved an underlying parsing issue, enabling the class import to function properly.

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i52Y.png)

[it worked !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNwiQ.png)